# Python не возвращает память ОС?

Tags: python

Предположим на старте приложения потребовалось 1 Gb памяти. ОС выделила. Спустя некоторое время потребление сократилось до в среднем 100 Mb и так осталось в дальнейшем.

Насколько я понимаю, неиспользуемые 900 Mb так и останутся неиспользованными и не возвращенными ОС?

Comment: Если вы их и в самом деле не используете, то однажды до них доберётся сборщик мусора и вернёт их системе

Answer (score 0):

если вы выделили и потом не освободили, то конечно будет висеть до конца работы программы,
но ничего не мешает выделить 1100, записать результаты в 100 и освободить 1000

опять же - если такое приложение одно в системе, да и пусть себе этот гигабайт отъест, не очень и страшно :)

Comment: `но ничего не мешает выделить 1100, записать результаты в 100 и освободить 1000` ­— не с/с++, сильно не разбежишься.